# Popping the "Generalist" Badge

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag, badges

I was taking a look at the list of badges today and there's a few that no one in WB have managed to collect as yet.

So I took a look at the requirements for the "Generalist" badge where the wording confused me:

> Provide non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags

So what this means is you need 15 votes for any question that has tags in the top 40 tags.

[This query](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/631411/generalist-progression) will show your personal progression towards that requirement

I'm almost at that stage, and there's many people with higher reps and more answers than I, so I wondered why no one has the badge.

And then I'm told (thanks, Tim B) that [there's a threshold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85048/does-the-generalist-badge-require-15-score-total-or-15-score-per-tag/85049#85049) for the number of questions per tag (top 40 tags need to have over 200 questions each).

Most of our top 40 tags are there; we just have four left:

- [cities](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cities)
- [near-future](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/near-future)
- [moons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moons)
- [gravity](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gravity)

All of these badges have 190 or more questions.

As soon as these badges each get to the 200+ question threshold, the "Generalist" badge should be awarded to those who have earned it.

So, creating a few valid questions with these tags (or adding the tags to existing questions, where relevant) will help.

Comment: Here's a good start if you feel like it: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+gravity+-[gravity]

Comment: Maybe we need a tag challenge :) http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1758/should-we-have-weekly-topic-challenges

Comment: Nice digging Pete.  Also...I am writing a question with all four tags right now... :D

Comment: @James - Tim B helped with the 200 question threshold in chat.  Most thanks goes to him.

Comment: And the gravity edit spree has started...

Comment: Whoops, I refreshed the search after the first edit and didn't see the question bump to the top.  Just assumed that a tag edit wasn't a bump.  I guess some folks might get some rep votes for old questions now.

Comment: Yes, pretty much any edit bumps a question to the top - it's not the end of the world but does mean we either recommend either only doing 1 or 2 questions at a time (to minimize severity of impact) with a decent length break between or doing all the edits at once (to minimize duration of impact)

Comment: Yes, I found that out to my cost.  The rest of the tags shouldn't really take long to naturally increase their question count.

Comment: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/71978/the-impacts-of-the-moons-limited-gravity-on-the-design-of-a-moon-citys-transpo

Comment: @James - Apologies for the somewhat obvious answer.  Hopefully a better answer will be along in a few minutes time.  Please check the overhead signs for updates on arrival times.

Comment: All of these tags now have at least 200 questions. We'll just have to wait for the system to notice.

Comment: And you all may thank me with showers of upvoting....!

Comment: Interesting.  No influx of new badges yet.  I wonder whether it's a timing thing or there's another requirement unfulfilled.

Comment: @Pᴇᴛᴇ probably this will come next time you get points on an answer related to that badge. You need to trigger the check.

Comment: @PatJ After HDE posted above, it appears that some questions lost some tags (or we lost some questions) so one of the tags dropped below 200.  I'm not due to qualify the badge for a while, but there's many established users here who should qualify.  Possibly all 40 tags need to stay above 200 questions for a certain time before the badge opens.

Comment: @Pᴇᴛᴇ From what I can see in the tag list, none of the top 40 has below 200 and from running your query, there are a couple of high rep users who'd qualify - yet no badge has been awarded. I guess it's just a matter about time now, the system ought to check for eligible users eventually.

Comment: @Mrkvička - yeah.  Let's keep an eye on this for a few days and see what happens.  If it still doesn't get released after the weekend, I'll post something on the main Stack meta and see if there's any explanation.

Answer (score 6):

Boom, we now have the "Generalist" badge.

We needed **over 200** questions in 20 of the top 40 tags.

Comment: I just have been awarded that badge, so I was just writing that obtaining it is possible

Comment: Yes, I just had to tag two questions to get their tags count over 200.

Comment: It just got to me, too.

Comment: Yeah, 69 people got it all at once.  That one was a tricky one to understand.

Comment: Aw. I felt special until I read that I was just 1 of 69. ;-)

Comment: @SRM Yeah, it's not fun to be just one in a 69, it's much better if there are two ;)

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations to all who got the badge!

Answer (score 0):

Don't feel like killing your buzz, but today I was awarded this *Generalist* badge. I am sorry if it hurt you in any manner :(

Also, I was quite confused when I looked at the description of the tag and could not understand why/how I had earned it.

> Provide non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags

What does that even mean?

Comment: It means you have enough points in enough different tags. Since we just popped up the tag requirements so that it could be done, a lot of people acquired the badge at once, including you.